# Could not find method on interface org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.StatementHandler named prepare

Tags: java, mybatis, interceptor, ibatis

I used Mybatis to create an Interceptor, but when I run it the console displayed there is no "prepare" named method in StatementHandler class. Is there anything else I need to do?

This is the annotation:

```
@Intercepts({ @Signature(type = StatementHandler.class, method = "prepare", args = { Connection.class, Integer.class }) })
```

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error opening session.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.plugin.PluginException: Could not find method on interface org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.StatementHandler named prepare. Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.StatementHandler.prepare(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection, java.lang.Integer)
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.plugin.PluginException: Could not find method on interface org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.StatementHandler named prepare. Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.StatementHandler.prepare(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection, java.lang.Integer)
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)   org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory.openSessionFromDataSource(DefaultSqlSessionFactory.java:100)
org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory.openSession(DefaultSqlSessionFactory.java:47)
    com.fj.db.DBAccess.getSqlSession(DBAccess.java:30)
    com.fj.dao.MessageDao.count(MessageDao.java:121)
    com.fj.service.QueryService.queryMessageList(QueryService.java:34)
    com.fj.servlet.ListServlet.doGet(ListServlet.java:46)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause
org.apache.ibatis.plugin.PluginException: Could not find method on interface org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.StatementHandler named prepare. Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.StatementHandler.prepare(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection, java.lang.Integer)
    org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.getSignatureMap(Plugin.java:87)
    org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.wrap(Plugin.java:44)
    com.fj.interceptor.PageInterceptor.plugin(PageInterceptor.java:121)
org.apache.ibatis.plugin.InterceptorChain.pluginAll(InterceptorChain.java:31)
org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.newExecutor(Configuration.java:553)
org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory.openSessionFromDataSource(DefaultSqlSessionFactory.java:96)
org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory.openSession(DefaultSqlSessionFactory.java:47)
    com.fj.db.DBAccess.getSqlSession(DBAccess.java:30)
    com.fj.dao.MessageDao.count(MessageDao.java:121)
    com.fj.service.QueryService.queryMessageList(QueryService.java:34)
    com.fj.servlet.ListServlet.doGet(ListServlet.java:46)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.StatementHandler.prepare(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection, java.lang.Integer)
    java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.getSignatureMap(Plugin.java:84)
    org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.wrap(Plugin.java:44)
    com.fj.interceptor.PageInterceptor.plugin(PageInterceptor.java:121)
org.apache.ibatis.plugin.InterceptorChain.pluginAll(InterceptorChain.java:31)
org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.newExecutor(Configuration.java:553)
org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory.openSessionFromDataSource(DefaultSqlSessionFactory.java:96) org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory.openSession(DefaultSqlSessionFactory.java:47)
    com.fj.db.DBAccess.getSqlSession(DBAccess.java:30)
    com.fj.dao.MessageDao.count(MessageDao.java:121)
    com.fj.service.QueryService.queryMessageList(QueryService.java:34)
    com.fj.servlet.ListServlet.doGet(ListServlet.java:46)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: What methods does the documentation say are there?

Comment: The method named "prepare" can not be found in org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.StatementHandler when execute the program. but there is one indeed.

Comment: Are you sure the parameter types you are using are correct? The documentation I found doesn't say the method has an Integer parameter

Comment: The "prepare" method is declared with "public interface StatementHandler {

  Statement prepare(Connection connection, Integer transactionTimeout)
      throws SQLException;" in the interface. And I also  tried without the Integer parameter. same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of your interceptor uses wrong `Connection` class. You are using `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection` but you should use `java.sql.Connection`. This line in the log gives you exact reason of the problem

```
 NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.StatementHandler.prepare(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection, java.lang.Integer)
```

The method in `StatementHandler` is defined as

```
java.sql.Statement prepare(java.sql.Connection connection)
```